# PHP - Find next available time slot

Tags: php, date, time, comparison

I'm looking for help in writing a script to find the next available time slot.

Ex:  Person A wants an appointment and the available time slots everyday is 9am, 12pm, 4pm, 6pm, 9pm

So, I need to check existing data and compare the time slots booked for the other appointments and then find next available.

```
$apts = array(
        'Person 1' => '1/1/09-9:00',
        'Person 2' => '1/1/09-12:00',
        'Person 3' => '1/1/09-18:00',
        'Person 4' => '1/1/09-21:00'
        );
```

So, I need to find next time slot for Person A against $apts, and it should come up with 4pm (1/1/09-16:00).  Then comes along Person B and the next time slot for him/her should be '1/2/09-9:00', since no more time slots on 1/1/09, so go to 9am next day.

Make since?
Thanks!!

Comment: How do you specify the possible time slots (i.e. taking into account holidays, etc)?  i.e. do you have another array with that information, or are you planning to just code it in?

Comment: Just code it in.  Not taking into account any special occassions or anything.

Comment: Sounds like a problem readily solved by a database.

Comment: is $apts a huge array containing all possible appointments for the year, or is it generated from a DB for each day?

Answer (score 1):

A database would be the best solution semantically speaking. If you want to use one table with columns `time` and `person_id`, where `time` is encoded as UNIX time (easily adaptable to other formats though), you might just want to run:

```
SELECT time FROM table WHERE person_id = 0 AND time > 1234567890 LIMIT 1;
```

Keeping to your original PHP only solution, a semantically sensible solution might just be to run a while loop to search for the next available time slot.

```
$timeslot = $desired_timeslot;
while(in_array($timeslot, $apts)) {
    $timeslot = get_next_timeslot($timeslot);
}
return $timeslot;
```

Of course, you'll have to define the function `get_next_timeslot()` to suit your encoding/organizing method.

Comment: don't use unix timestamps in your database, it makes running normal queries difficult. if you ever want to select a proper datetime as a unix timestamp, use UNIX_TIMESTAMP(column)